# How to call a ajax function before loading any partuclar view page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, timezone

I have a view page below which automatically detects the current user timezone and after detecting timezone , i am sending it to another page for setting the timezone in session for further use.

here is the file(autodetect.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="....jquery.js' ?>"></script>  
      <script type="text/javascript"       src='..autodetect/Jsfile/detect1.0.4.min.js'>   
</script> 
 <script>  
 $(function() {   

   <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['tz'])) { ?>
        var timezone = jstz.determine(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url('timezone.php'); ?>",
            data: 'timezone='+timezone.name(),
            success: function(data){ 
            }
        }); 
        <?php } ?>   
    }); 
 </script>   
 </head> 
 <body>  
 </body>
```

,in order to perform this functionality i have to load/read this page(autodetect.php) first,

so my question is **"how can i run this page(i.e `autodetect.php`) before loading any view page or calling any view page via controller?**

eg. i have to load the signup page , but before then this i need to read the above php file in order to detect the current timezone of user.

Comment: Hi All! If my above question is not clear, please write comment for me, so that i will try to explain you in a different way. Thanks

Comment: Apparently, this has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone

Comment: @Ponce That is not similar with my problem. I am asking a diffrent thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load any script before loading any view page, you can use Hooks:

[Hooks - Extending the Framework Core](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

And choose the appropriate **hook point** for your need.